# Gojs - Order of Diagram elements in canvas differ between chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have part which has panel that has shape and svg image added to diagram.
This is followed by nodetemplate and then followed by groupTemplate.

1]  myDiagram.add(
        $$(go.Part, "Table",

2]  myDiagram.nodeTemplate =

3]  myDiagram.groupTemplate =

The rendering of the diagram in **chrome** is : 
[image]

The rendering of the diagram in **Mozilla** is :
[image]

Why is red circle and text appear at bottom in mozilla....???

**The rendering in IE and Chrome is same** but differs with mozilla. can anyone help out!!

Thanks

Comment: @Simon Sarris any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tis is happening is because Chrome's `Array.sort` is not a stable sort. This means that if you have to sort a list of elements and there is no criteria to determine that one should go before the other, then its possible the resulting sorted list will be sorted in a different order than the order they came in.

The solution is to use some criteria for sorting these objects. You can do this by setting a [layout's comparer function](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GridLayout.html#comparer).

By default the comparer function looks at `Part.text`, which has not been specified in your case, so each of your parts is equivalent, so Chrome's unstable sort mixes their order since (if they are equivalent), it doesn't think it matters.

To fix this, use something each part has in the order you want, for instance creating `data.text` or `data.order` or something, and compare using that:

```
// NOTE this assumes data.text exists!
// You could use anything as long as it describes the order
function myCompareFunction(a, b) {
  var at = a.data.text; 
  var bt = b.data.text;
  if (at < bt) return -1;
  if (at > bt) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Then in your layout definition add:

```
        layout:
        $(go.GridLayout,
          { ....... comparer: myCompareFunction })
```

Comment: I tried adding order property but it said "cannot set undefined property order. ". Then I added text to each part without comparator function. It worked. I added comparator function then too it worked. any reason why order property didnt work? Thanks again!!

Comment: `order` isn't a property, I was just suggesting adding it to the node data when you add it to your model: `{ key: 5, order: 1 }` etc